# How to enable treble support in old devices?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, custom-roms, treble

Today, I am back to challenge you all. As you would have guessed from the question title, this post is to know about enabling treble support on old phones. Of course, there are a lot of guides on the internet about this and I **"will"** explain how this post is different from them.

First, we have a post about this on this very site.

Link: [Enabling Project Treble in non-Treble Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224381/enabling-project-treble-in-non-treble-android)

Here, the question has not been properly answered so this is not helpful.

I found the next link from the above link.

Link: https://www.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-redmi-note-4-project-treble/

This is specific to redmi note 4. So, provides no help to non MIUI users.

Now, we can definitely install a custom rom to enable treble but such roms are not available for all devices.

So, now, let me be specific with my device. I have a device running Android 5.1 with MediaTek MT6735 processor. Now, I have searched a lot in the internet about custom roms and have installed many roms and have **"many times hard bricked my phone"**. With no options left with me and you not annoyed by reading so much, can you please give me a way I can enable treble support using a similar way found in the above XDA post? Or any other way, if you know? And please don't, just don't tell me to either buy a new phone or give up trying to enable treble support on my device.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The question [Enabling Project Treble in non-Treble Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224381/enabling-project-treble-in-non-treble-android) may not have an official answer but Irfan's comments contain everything you need to know. Modifying a running system to make it treble compliant is something out of scope for the majority of users. BTW: You don't need a ROM for your CPU but for your device, this means it has to be adapted to every single component in it (CPU, Wifi, Bluetooth, GPS, display, digitizer, camera, USB-chip, battery, buttons, ...)

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert. Yes, as you said, I need a rom for the device. And I don't have one yet. Hey, can Irfan's process be applied to any device? Wait... Sorry, I didn't clearly mention my device. You can find my device specifications on https://m.gsmarena.com/micromax_canvas_mega_4g_q417-7901.php. I am waiting for some more responses.

Comment: If you are a very experienced ROM developer you may be able to do it on most devices. But for your device I would assume that you simple need an ROM for this specific device. And if you don't find one this is it. Use it or replace it - and my recommendation would be to check if there are custom ROMs (or better LineageOS support) before buying a new device. And don't forget to download interesting ROMs because 5 years after the release most ROMs are already gone. Therefore having some ROMS in stock even without using them is a good idea together with an archived  how-to install page.

Comment: @VD-Flash the last part of my comment: *"Theoretically Treble can be enabled on every device provided that sources are available for the device. And it's a matter of how much effort one has to put into it."* As Robert said if you are not an experienced ROM developer, you can't do anything about it. Your primary concern is developing a ROM, adding Treble support is secondary (and unnecessary too), though both are off-topic here.

Comment: Well, I surely am a programmer and developer but a computer programmer and have very little experience with android. So... yeah, I cannot develop a rom myself. And one more thing. I know that phones are completely different from computers but in case I find a rom for a device having completely identical hardware configuration as mine, will it be ok for me?

Comment: If by "completely identical hardware configuration" you mean exactly the same hardware starting from BootROM, SoC (including its components), motherboard and so on... then yes that'll be OK. But that doesn't happen very often except if you find some exactly identical devices manufactured by the same ODM but branded by different white-labelers (even they are very likely to differ in some configuration). So you need to port the ROM from one device to the other. And that's what ROM developers mostly do. Building from scratch is done only by OEMs. Again plz note that development is off-topic here.

Comment: Looks good. Hey, BTW, do you know any trusted porter for this job?

Comment: No, sorry. XDA forums is a good place to find one. // Btw other users don't get notified of your comments unless you tag them.

Comment: @<Irfan Latif> As your opinion, I posted a thread on XDA. Let's see what happens. And thanks for all your help.